# BQ doesn't reduce the query cost

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a question regarding the BQ cost optimization. In my case I have a table which stores some date parameters used to perform further filtration. So basically after running the subquery to get the date params from params table, I run query on the table with data and try to reduce the query costs, based on the provided filtering conditions.

Unfortunatelly, the BQ engine is not able to reduce the query costs (it read entire table even if the filter condition is applied). Any ideas and workarounds?

And example bellow:

```
WITH date_range as (
    SELECT
        min(DATE_KEY) as min_date_key,
        max(DATE_KEY) as max_date_key
    FROM <TABLE_WITH_DATA_PARAMS>
)


SELECT * FROM <TABLE_WITH_DATA>
-- this filtering condition doesn't reduce the query costs
WHERE DATE_KEY between -- DATE_KEY is partitioned field
    (SELECT min_date_key FROM date_range) and 
    (SELECT max_date_key FROM date_range)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, in general a `WHERE` clause does not reduce the amount of data scanned unless the table is [partitioned and/or clustered](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs#use_clustered_or_partitioned_tables). I understand that your table is indeed partitioned by field `DATE-KEY`.

In this case, if I am not mistaken, the issue is with dynamic expressions. Given that the values of `min_date_key` and `max_date_key` are set depending on the value of `date_range` which depends on `<table_with_data_params>` (meaning is dynamically assigned) this makes BigQuery scan all partitions. 
See the second example in [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables?hl=pl#pruning_limiting_partitions) where it is explained.

Also, notice that you should avoid `SELECT *` as a [best practice](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs#avoid_select_) to control costs unless it is unavoidable.

Comment: Indeed, my tabke is partitioned by DATE_KEY and data ranges are dynamically assigned. I used * just for demonstration purposes to not bother you with collumn names, which are not reevant in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Some Bigquery cost [optimization techniques](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/cost-optimization-best-practices-for-bigquery) are given below :-

> **Cost optimization techniques in BigQuery: query processing**

1. Only query the data you need.
2. Set up controls for accidental human errors.
3. Use caching intelligently.
4. Partition your tables.
5. Further reduce sweeping your data using clustering.

> **Understanding flat-rate vs. on-demand pricing**

For your use case Partition/Clustering your should implement if not implemented.